# How to define and compile a JDK module in Android Studio with Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-7, build.gradle

I would like to compile a JDK outside of the Java implementation that an Android project uses for a particular model.  I'm running into an issue where the javax language modifier can't be resolved, because it's using Android's java implementation. I wish to define and compile this as a JDK, not sure if it's correct or not. Here's my gradle compile of the module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.5.1'

}
```

Currently I get that

> Failed resolution of: Ljavax/lang/model/element/Modifier;

which indicates to me that it is using the Android implementation of Java.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean by "compile as a JDK". Maybe JAR file?

Comment: Correct, a Jar is compiled via the JDK.